# Syntax Highlighting in posts

Tags: wygwam

I'm trying to build a blog in ExpressionEngine that supports syntax highlighting in posts, so that snippets of code in the post will be displayed with line numbers, syntax highlighting, etc.

In WordPress you use the SyntaxHighlighter Evolved plugin to do this (http://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/). You wrap the snippet of code to highlight in shortcodes, and the actual highlighting is done on the front end with javascript (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

In ExpressionEngine??? I thought I would do it the same way: wygwam uses CKEditor, and CKEditor has a plugin to generate the html that the javascript SyntaxHighlighter operates on. The problem I have is that I don't want to include the syntax highlighting javascript on every blog page, just on the ones that need it. How to identify them?

Or, is there some other way entirely I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work.
Use:

- http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ for javascript syntax
  highlighting.
- http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/api/autoloader.html
  for dynamic brush loading so you don't need 30 js files on every page
- ckeditor http://ckeditor.com/ for the editor (use wygwam)
- http://ckeditor.com/addon/syntaxhighlight for syntaxhighlighting in ckeditor
- http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-syntaxhighlighter to add
  the ckeditor plugin to wygwam (except you need to update this to the
  most recent ckeditor plugin)

And then everything works...